# Whats the thread thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=exc_i386_gpflt) and how to solve it?C++

Tags: c++, xcode6

I'm working on a tourist guide using c++, and I keep getting this thread when I run the code, in the Attraction class, setName function, and in the main function, and I dont understand what's the issue. Here's the .cpp and main files.

```
//.cpp file
#include <string>
#include "Attraction.h"

    string Attraction::getName(){
        return name;
    }

    int Attraction::getIDType(){
        return id;
    }
    void Attraction::setName(string name){
        this -> name = name;//In this line I receive the thread
    }

    void Attraction::setIDType(int typeID){
        this -> typeID = typeID;
    }
//main.cpp
    int main() {
    int x;
    City Rome(111,"Rome");
    City Dubai(222,"Dubai");
    City Paris(333, "Paris");
    menu(Rome,Dubai,Paris);
    Sport* Ds = new Sport[x];
    Culture* Dc = new Culture[x];
    Shopping* Dh = new Shopping[x];
//{new Sport,new Sport,new Sport,new Culture,new Culture,new Culture,new Shopping,new Shopping,new Shopping};
    Ds[0].setName("Camel and Horse Racing");
    Ds[1].setName("Marine Sports");
    Ds[2].setName("Football");
    Dc[0].setName("Dubai Museum");
    Dc[1].setName("Falconry");
    Dc[2].setName("Sheikh Saeed Al-Maktoum's House");
    Dh[0].setName("Dubai Mall");//And here
    Dh[1].setName("Mall of Emirates");
    Dh[2].setName("Deira City Centre");
    Ds[0].setIDType(1);
    Ds[1].setIDType(1);
    Ds[2].setIDType(1);
    Ds[3].setIDType(2);
    Ds[4].setIDType(2);
    Ds[5].setIDType(2);
    Ds[6].setIDType(3);
    Ds[7].setIDType(3);
    Ds[8].setIDType(3);


    Dubai.setAttraction(Ds, x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're writing C++ as though it's the same thing as Java. As a result, this code is leaks memory. You should `delete[]` the arrays that you `new` and you should read `Bjarne Stroustroup's C++11 book` to understand memory management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your C++ code, you're creating a dynamic array of size `x` but you never assign a value to x, which means it has a default value of 0.

That means that the following lines create empty arrays:

```
Sport* Ds = new Sport[x];
Culture* Dc = new Culture[x];
Shopping* Dh = new Shopping[x];
```

So when you call `Ds[0].setName()`,you get a Segmentation Fault because you're calling a method on a bad address.

In order to fix this issue, Make sure you give a valid size for each array. Here is an example:

```
int main()
{

    Sport* Ds = new Sport[9];
    Ds[0].setIDType(1);
    Ds[0].setName("Camel and Horse Racing");
    Ds[1].setName("Marine Sports");
    Ds[2].setIDType(1);
    Ds[2].setName("Football");
    Ds[3].setIDType(2);
    Ds[4].setIDType(2);
    Ds[5].setIDType(2);
    Ds[6].setIDType(3);
    Ds[7].setIDType(3);
    Ds[8].setIDType(3);

    Culture* Dc = new Culture[3];
    Dc[0].setName("Dubai Museum");
    Dc[1].setName("Falconry");
    Dc[2].setName("Sheikh Saeed Al-Maktoum's House");

    Shopping* Dh = new Shopping[3];
    Dh[0].setName("Dubai Mall");//And here
    Dh[1].setName("Mall of Emirates");
    Dh[2].setName("Deira City Centre");

    delete[] Ds;
    delete[] Dc
    delete[] Dh;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but then I'd have to this for the others which is quite the long process. Do you suggest any other way, or should I just use vectors instead.